# Can I execute highlighted text in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

It looks like there are options for keyboard shortcuts to execute the current chunk, paragraph and section.

Can I have a keyboard shortcut that will let me highlight text and then run just that text?

Comment: Rmd is a textual format, not an interpreter. Any keyboard shortcuts are part of the IDE you are using. Is it RStudio? (That is not the only one, that's why I ask.) If yes, then see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts and https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/rstudio-shortcuts.html.

Comment: That answered my question, thanks

Comment: If I click run this paragraph and then I click the same thing for another paragraph, will they run sequentially?

Comment: They run in the order you click them, so you can run them individually out of order if you want.